# Git: Making a small change (which is not part of a feature), while working in a feature branch

Tags: git, branch

I am working in a feature branch. I see a small typo/bug and I just want to fix it, or do a small change in code (which should also reflect in the global/master code), but it's not really part of the feature that I am working on at the moment.

What should I do?
Where should I commit the fix/change?

Comment: That's more a matter of taste, have e.g. a look at `git stash`

Answer (score 1):

- If it's a small change, and you will soon merge the feature branch anyway, you can fix it on the feature branch.
- Fix it on master, and if it's necessary for your work on the feature, rebase the feature branch onto it if you haven't pushed the feature branch yet, else merge it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate branch "hotfix" for these kinds of fixes. When you need to fix something small -

1. Checkout to that branch
2. do "git pull origin master (or whatever branch you use as master branch)"
3. push you commits
4. merge the branch with master

Comment: The pull might create an unnecessary merge commit and also mess up first-parent history. Just base the hotfix branch off of master.

Comment: Thanks @krisz. I guess I was doing it in an unnecessarily complex way.